# How to update PHP5 to latest stable PHP5 version?

Tags: opensuse, php

I can't find any infos on how to update PHP 5.5.14 to the latest PHP 5.6.37 which was released on 19 Jul 2018.

I executed `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` but PHP 5.5.14 is still installed.

**OS:** openSUSE Leap version 42.3

Comment: You should migrate to PHP 7.2 as soon as possible, as support for 5.6 ends on Dec 31st.

Comment: Do you use SuSE or Debian/Ubuntu? There is discrepancy between your question and tags

Comment: Which OS, which version? `apt-get` indicates your using a Debian / Debian-derived Linux. But all still supported Debian/Ubuntu/Mint etc. variants should have 5.6 and 7.2 or only 7.2. So I think you have a problem with your OS. [Find out](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-check-os-version-in-linux-command-line/) with `cat /etc/os-release` or `hostnamectl` and edit your question adding that information.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I am using Suse and what discrepancy do you mean exactly?

Comment: @RoVo, Thats not possible. I am using Magento 1.8 which only supports php 5.

Comment: @Black, as already mentioned by RoVo `apt-get` is Debian way, not SuSE

Comment: @RoVo, I am using `Linux version 4.4.159-73-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.8.5 (SUSE Linux)`.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, then why does `apt-get` work on my Suse?

Comment: @Black, because someone install it. The canonical command (for SuSE) is `zypper`: https://www.suse.com/documentation/opensuse110/opensuse110_reference/data/sec_zypper.html

Comment: So no one knows how to upgrade to php 5.6?

Answer (score 0):

You can build php on your own and use --with-prefix or --prefix, i.e. /usr/local/php.

If you are not sure what to put behind ./configure command you can copy it from current PHP, it is visible in phpinfo() (compiled with...).

Just, don't forget to use --prefix switch for configure.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for openSUSE packages on software.opensuse.org, you should land [here](https://software.opensuse.org/package/php-5.6.37?search_term=%22php%205.6.37%22). This would show you a non-official build, so be very careful and make sure you can roll back to a previous state. If you decide to give it a try, add the respective repo to your system and try to install a newer version.

```
# Add repo
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Cloud:/Platform:/buildpacks:/dependencies/openSUSE_Leap_42.3/ php-5

# List php-5 packages
zypper se -s php-5  

Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S  | Name       | Type       | Version    | Arch   | Repository
---+------------+------------+------------+--------+-----------
   | php-5.6.37 | srcpackage | 5.6.37-1.1 | noarch | php-5.6   
i+ | php-5.6.37 | package    | 5.6.37-1.1 | x86_64 | php-5.6   
   | php-5.6.38 | srcpackage | 5.6.38-1.1 | noarch | php-5.6   
   | php-5.6.38 | package    | 5.6.38-1.1 | x86_64 | php-5.6
```

There's a newer version available, so install it:

```
zypper in php-5.6.38

The following NEW package is going to be installed:
  php-5.6.38

1 new package to install.
Overall download size: 2.2 KiB. Already cached: 0 B. No additional space will be used or freed after the operation.
Continue? [y/n/...? shows all options] (y):
```